# Windows 10: Use Skype as microphon

Tags: windows, windows-10, audio

since yesterday my headset's microphone is not working anymore, so I'm searching for a way around this without investing in new hardware.

So I looked for apps wich are enabling my smartphone as a microphone (via 3,5 - 3,5 cable); none of them seemed to work.

Now I am thinking about using skyping with my phone while I would need to use my microphone.

Is there a way to mute the output and use it as an input for e.g. Teamspeak?

Is there maybe an application wich creates two audiochannels, one as an speaker and one as an line-in and synchs the out-input of them?

I'm sorry for the bad description and missing knowledge.

For german people:

Die Frage ist, ob es ein Programm gibt, dass ein Wiedergabegerät und ein Aufnahmegerät simuliert, bei welchen der Sound, der in das Wiedergabegerät eingespeist wird (wenn es bzw. bei Skype als Lautsprecher angewählt ist) über das Aufnahmegerät ausgegeben wird.

Thanks for any help or advises,

Carroll

Comment: [This site](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com) is catered more towards software recs.

Comment: You are asking an off-topic question (software shopping). Questions seeking product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic. See [On Topic](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic). Try http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/  but please first read [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information).